# getAbsolutePath() not working on Jar file

Tags: java, jar

so I am trying to work with GUI java and this code works fine whenever I try to run my code in my terminal, however I need to create a jar file that can load a text file from any directory (sadly this code only works for files
in my home directory, if I try to access the files from different folders it returns a file exception) Would really appreciate responses. I dunno if this matters but I am implementing a serializable interface.

```
public boolean loadCanvas(String filename){
        boolean done = true;
        try{
            File file = new File(filename);
            FileInputStream fp = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
            ObjectInputStream i = new ObjectInputStream(fp);
            obj = (A) i.readObject();
            i.close();
        }
        catch(Exception eRef){
            done = false;
        }
        return done;    
    }
```

Comment: You can't load files this way from JAR; you have to getResourceAsStream using the class loader.

Comment: Did you `System.err.println(file.getAbsolutePath())` and check the path? Then, add at least `eRef.printStackTrace()` to your exception handler - currently you are ignoring all exceptions.

Comment: @duffymo He says he wants to load the text file from any **directory** ...

Comment: Yes, I see that.  Can't be done this way.  The exception is giving him the answer.

Comment: "it returns a file exception" is not a problem description. Try again.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to call `getAbsolutePath()` at all. The String variable filename should contain the full path you are trying to access. You can instantiate FileInputStream with either your File object or just the String, filename (e.g. `new FileInputStream(file)` or `new FileInputStream(filename)`). That being said, it sounds like your problem is that you have an improper filepath specified in your filename variable or you are running into permission restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to load the file using ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(). Also,
have you checked the permissions of the files you are trying to access outside your home directory?

Comment: That won't work 'from any directory'. It will only work from within the JAR file. It isn't clear what the OP's actual problem is, but this solution doesn't agree with the question.